# Launching a new terminal and running commands

Tags: python, postgresql, ubuntu

I am writing an app where the administrator  has to input his username and password.  And by doing that, a terminal is launched in ubuntu and has the following commands:

```
adduser admin
passwd admin
su - postgres
psql postgres
# run postgres ccommands ie grant all privileges with a password for the user
```

I do not want the user to type anything because the form provides the names of the database for postgres and the username and password for postgres...

All the user needs to input are his passwords and administrator system passwords.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking us to write the program for you, or is there a specific part of the problem you don't understand?

Comment: i know i can write this in pythi python: os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"sudo adduser tom\"'").  Can I write multiple lines??

Comment: I just want the piece of code where i can launch the ubuntu terminal and automatically run certain commands.. More than one to be precise.. i can run only a command but I would want to run many commands in the terminal window

Comment: Ogo- edit your question to add that code that you do have, and the precise question that you have (and described in the comments here).  That will help you get some answers.  I'll add the edits and hopefully it will be what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to launch a terminal, you need to pass the command list to the shell spawned by the terminal. The syntax for this depends somewhat on the terminal used.

For `gnome-terminal` you want:

```
gnome-terminal -e '... command ...'
```

e.g.

```
gnome-terminal -e 'sh -c "adduser admin && passwd admin && sudo -u postgres psql"'
```

I suggest using `sudo` not `su` though, as shown above.

The `&&` means "only run the next command if the previous one returned zero (succeeded)"